# Triggering pipeline using azure function when data is uploaded

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was looking for other question which could be similar to mine, but wasn't able to find something like this.

**Question**: Pictures are uploaded to a platform, which I can access using an API, sometimes 3 times a day, something once a week. Instead of running a scheduled pipeline, we want to trigger the pipeline when new data is uploaded to the platform. I've used a timer function (every 5 minutes) at the moment, but cannot find how to trigger a specific pipeline. So how can I do this?
***Good to know:*** The pipeline starts a job in Azure ML in a compute cluster.
Does anyone know the solution to my question or know where I can find more information about this?

Comment: I removed the [tag:azure-pipelines] tag, as the tag is for the Azure Pipelines service and has nothing to do with ML or data factory pipelines. Please review your tags and ensure they are appropriate for the question.

Answer (score 0):

If your Azure ML job (or pipeline) can send the picture to Azure Blob Storage, then your Azure Function can be triggered based whenever a new image is uploaded. Here are tutorials on how to do this in [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-upload-function-trigger?tabs=azure-portal) and [Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/blob-upload-function-trigger-javascript?tabs=storage-resource-visual-studio-code%2Ccomputer-vision-azure-portal).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to do this process in the opposite way. To prevent the ML job running for no reason, we want to only run this Azure ML job when new images are available (which can be checked using an Azure function). Running the evaluation code locally is no option, since many computations needs to be done, which will take a long time

Comment: I just thought about a completely different solution, but I'm not sure whether it will work, so I need to try that: I have an Azure function that scans the API whether it received an image. If it received an image then I'll create an Azure Job using some code in the Azure Function. I'm not sure whether this will work, but it was something I just thought about. Any comments?

Comment: Since I cannot edited the comments above I will do it in this way: I'm using https://github.com/zylo117/Yet-Another-EfficientDet-Pytorch, which also has to be included in the Azure ML Job. Does this make sense?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I had assumed that your Azure ML job was the component that uploaded the image to your platform. Does the platform (assuming not any of the supported triggers) have a webhook? If it does, you can make that platform call your Azure Function when a new image shows up on the platform. Otherwise, with Azure Functions, your options are limited to using the Timer trigger to poll the platform's API at an interval.

Comment: don't worry. the platform does not have a webhook, so I'm kind of forced to use Timer triggers. My question is then whether (and how) it's possible to send a 'signal' to a pipeline, so that the new uploaded images can be evaluated in an Azure ML job. A function would be too slow to process the image(s), which will take too long. That's why a ML job is needed